# What is UV decomposition?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

As I'm reading about different matrix decomposition methods, I see a reference to a decomposition method that is known as UV method where:

- U: has small number of columns
- V: has small number of rows

Surprisingly, I don't find any reference on what UV is, on algorithms to get UV, and on where to use UV. Could anyone please guide me on where I can learn more about this decomposition method?

Comment: Maybe QR decomposition? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_decomposition)

Comment: I haven't heard about UV-decomposition, while low-rank (approximated) decompositions are frequently written as $A = U \Sigma V$ or $A = U V$ with U and V satisfying the properties you named

Comment: Look at section 9.4.1 of http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/mmds/ch9.pdf .  Then glance through http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/mmds/ch11.pdf . Also http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/149262/what-is-the-relationship-between-svd-and-uv-decomposition .

Comment: +1 @MarkL.Stone. This is a relatively rare decomposition used in recommender systems. I would strongly suggest using some "cheap" SVD alternative.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone: I wasn't surprised to see you talking about matrix algebra. I was surprised to see you citing literature on recommender systems. :)

Comment: @Cliff AB I'm not recommending any of this recommender cr@p; merely providing links relevant to the posted question :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $A$ is a matrix of rank $k$ and size $m$ by $n$, $A$ can be written as

$A=UV^{T}$

where $U$ is of size $m$ by $k$ and $V$ is of size $n$ by $k$. The columns of $U$ and $V$ need not necessarily be orthogonal.

If you have the SVD of $A$, then it's easy to compute this low rank factorization from the SVD.  Given the SVD

$A=U\Sigma V^{T}$

where $\Sigma$ is a diagonal matrix with only the first $k$ entries of $\Sigma$ nonzero, we can write $A$ as

$A=U_{:,1:k} \Sigma_{1:k,1:k} V_{:,1:k}^{T}$.

The scaling factors on the diagonal of $\Sigma_{1:k,1:k}$ can be incorporated into $V$ so that $A$ and can be written as $A=UV^{T}$.

However, computing the singular value decomposition of a large matrix can be extremely expensive, and the resulting $U$ and $V$ matrices would typically be fully dense.

There are specialized algorithms for heuristically finding low rank approximations of matrices that are faster than computing a full SVD.  Some of these methods find sparse $U$ and $V$ matrices and
also deal with the case where $A$ is only approximately of rank $k$ (e.g. due to noise in the entries.)  There is a lot of current interest in low rank matrix factorization algorithms of various sorts.