# Is it possible to apply matrix decomposition to a vector, injecting additional information to UV decomposition?

Tags: machine-learning, linear-algebra, recommender-system, svd, matrix-decomposition

As I am reading about recommender systems in Machine Learning, UV decomposition caught my eye ([click](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/189730/what-is-uv-decomposition) for an explanation or see below).

So I have two questions:

**Question 1:** what are the drawbacks of trying to UV-decompose a *1* by *m* vector into a product of a *1* by *d* ( $U$ ) vector and a *d* by *m* matrix ($V$)?

As far as I can see, the problem arises from the fact that the system is poorly constrained. Is it so? How can I relate that fact to the rank of the original matrix?

**Question 2:** Imagine that we have two matrices. Matrix $A$ is a user-item *n* by *m* matrix. Matrix $B$ is a *1* by *m* vector describing certain characteristics of items. Is it possible to overcome the problem of poor constraint by constructing the decomposition as following: $A \approx U_1V^{T}$, $B \approx U_2V^{T}$? Note that $V^{T}$ matrix is shared by both decompositions and thus we expect the constraints of matrix A to bind the solution.

Please also note that the optimization function will then look (roughly) like that:
$$\min J = ||A - U_1V^{T}||_2^2 + \beta ||B - U_2V^{T}||_2^2$$

Effectively, what I am trying to achieve is to inject some item-related side information from a matrix $B$ to the solution. What are the cons of doing so?

Thanks!

---

More on UV decomposition:

> Consider movies as a case in point. Most users respond to a small number
> of features; they like certain genres, they may have certain famous actors or
> actresses that they like, and perhaps there are a few directors with a significant
> following. If we start with the utility matrix M, with n rows and m columns
> (i.e., there are n users and m items), then we might be able to find a matrix
> U with n rows and d columns and a matrix V with d rows and m columns,
> such that UV closely approximates M in those entries where M is nonblank.
> If so, then we have established that there are d dimensions that allow us to
> characterize both users and items closely. We can then use the entry in the
> product UV to estimate the corresponding blank entry in utility matrix M.
> This process is called UV-decomposition of M.

[image]